# How to disable parallax when a bootstrap modal is opened?

Tags: modal-dialog, parallax

My website home page uses parallax. I have a button in my home page which opens a modal when clicked. The problem is if I scroll over the modal to see overflown modal body content, the background i.e html body starts scrolling. Clicking or hovering over the modal doesn't make any difference. But when I disable parallax modal works perfectly.

How can I achieve default modal functionality thereby keeping parallax feature also ?

Comment: you can use bootstrap modal event listeners http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events